# Label Encoding of Categorical values for Future df

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, label-encoding

I am building a model where `LabelEncoding` of 2 categorical columns is a better approach. So I had implemented the same on the `train_df` and finalized the model.

And for predicting the `test_df`, I used to fit the 2 categorical columns on `train_df` and then transform the values on `test_df` as something like below:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(train_df)

le.transform(test_df)
```

Now I have to save and give the `.pkl` file of the model to some other team. If in this case, they want to use the model, do they have to fit the labelencoding on `train_df` again and then transform on their new data?

Answer (score 1):

You should save (e.g. as another pickle) your fitted LabelEncoder and provide that along with the model, and instructions (a python script/snippet?) for how to use them to reach a final prediction (`le.transform` then `model.predict`).

You might consider using a `Pipeline` (and potentially [other composite estimators](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipelines-and-composite-estimators)) from `sklearn` to package all of that into one object that just needs to `predict`.

N.B., `LabelEncoder` is supposed to be used for target variables (and even then mostly just internally), you would probably be slightly better off with `OrdinalEncoder`.  See e.g. [this DS.SE question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/39317/55122).